# Is it possible to pass a instance method as an argument without knowing the instance in Python

Tags: python

I want to pass an instance method to another function but when I do I don't know from which instance that will be. I only know the base class from which those instances are derived. Is there a way to call the instance method from inside the function?

I have the following code:

```
class Base:
    def do_something():
        pass        


class InstanceOne(Base):
    def do_something():
        print("Instance One")


class InstanceTwo(Base):
    def do_something():
        print("Instance Two")


def my_function(instances_list: List[Base], method)
    for instance in instances_list:
        instance.method()


# The main part
my_list = [InstanceOne(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceOne()]
my_function(my_list, Base.do_something)
```

The code above won't work because the function `do_something` is called on the `Base` class and not on the instances. Is there a way to actually call the instances's methods `do_something` when the function (`my_function`) doesn't know what the instances will be?

Comment: More than that, you're calling the method named "`.method`" on all instances. The parameter `method` is never used.

Comment: @deceze: yes you are absolutely right. I used this code to make my problem clear. If I would only have called `method` then maybe it wasn't clear I wanted to call the instances method.

Comment: The code does not work for reasons unrelated to what you say and the instances are known both to the main program and `my_function`. What is preventing you from just calling `instance.do_something()` on each element of the list (other than the method definition being wrong)?

Comment: @Goyo: this was a simplification with more code surrounding the loop in `my_function`.

Comment: So what? Do you want `my_function` to call `.do_something()` on each instance? Do you want something else?

Comment: `.do_something` should only be called under certain conditions: `my_function` checks those conditions before calling `.do_something`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `operator.methodcaller`

```
def my_function(instances_list: List[Base], method_name):
    method = methodcaller(method_name)
    for instance in instances_list:
        method(instance)
```

Also your functions are methods, they need to accept a `self` argument.

Your code should look as follows:

```
from operator import methodcaller

class Base:
    def do_something(self):
        pass        


class InstanceOne(Base):
    def do_something(self):
        print("Instance One")


class InstanceTwo(Base):
    def do_something(self):
        print("Instance Two")


def my_function(instances_list, method_name):
    method = methodcaller(method_name)
    for instance in instances_list:
        method(instance)


# The main part
my_list = [InstanceOne(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceOne()]
my_function(my_list, 'do_something')
```

This outputs:

```
Instance One
Instance Two
Instance Two
Instance One
```

Answer (score 3):

this is because you do explicitly specify to use the method found in `Base`.

I propose two ways to solve it:

### Use `lambda`

You can use an anonymous lambda function to do what you want:

```py
def my_function(instances_list: List[Base], method)
    for instance in instances_list:
        method(instance)

# The main part
my_list = [InstanceOne(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceOne()]
my_function(my_list, lambda i: i.do_something())
```

### Use `getattr`

Another way to solve it in a more abstract manner is by using the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function and passing the method's name as a string.

> **getattr**(object, name[, default])
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

```py
def my_function(instances_list: List[Base], method_name)
    for instance in instances_list:
        getattr(instance, method_name)()

# The main part
my_list = [InstanceOne(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceOne()]
my_function(my_list, 'do_something')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by using `hasattr` and `getattr`

```
def my_function(instances_list: List[Base], method)
    for instance in instances_list:
        if hasattr(instance, method):
            getattr(instance, method)()
```

and call your function like

```
# The main part
my_list = [InstanceOne(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceOne()]
my_function(my_list, 'do_something')
```

Comment: `if hasattr(instance, method):` why? this should probably not fail silently.

Comment: And if it *should* fail silently I'd probably go with `getattr(instance, method, lambda: pass)()` instead.

Comment: @beer44 You should rename `method` to `method_name`.

Comment: @deceze , yes in this way it will fail silently and indeed you have suggested the best way way to do as one liner

Answer (score 1):

Use the actual method name through `method_object.__name__`.
See the corrected approach below:

```
from typing import List

class Base:
    def do_something(self):
        pass


class InstanceOne(Base):
    def do_something(self):
        print("Instance One")


class InstanceTwo(Base):
    def do_something(self):
        print("Instance Two")


def my_function(instances_list: List[Base], method_name):
    for instance in instances_list:
        getattr(instance, method_name)()


# The main part
my_list = [InstanceOne(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceTwo(), InstanceOne()]
my_function(my_list, Base.do_something.__name__)
```

The output:

```
Instance One
Instance Two
Instance Two
Instance One
```

Comment: May I suggest that this solution, while technically correct, is a bit convoluted (Rube Goldberg anyone ?) and not very efficient (wrt/ directly passing the method name as string) ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, not a big deal for such kind of declaim. You don't know whether that method object is planned to be somehow used further. I've changed to pass a method name so the community could be more satisfied (if it even cares)